# Why useState object value is not updating using onBlur event in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have textfield component

```
<MyTextField
    type={inpValues.emailID.type}
    label={inpValues.emailID.label}
    name={inpValues.emailID.name}
    placeholder={inpValues.emailID.placeHolder}
    required={inpValues.emailID.required}
    error={inpValues.emailID.error}
    helperText={inpValues.emailID.helperText}
    
    handleOnBlur={(event) => {
        //console.log("Call HandleOnBlur");
        setInpValues({...inpValues, email:{
            ...inpValues.emailID,
            value:event.target.value
        }})
        HandleEmailOnBlur(inpValues.emailID.value)
        }
    }
    value={inpValues.emailID.value}
></MyTextField>
```

**HandleEmailOnBlur function**

```
const HandleEmailOnBlur = (emailID) =>{
    if(emailID.trim().length > 0){
        let email = emailID;
        emailValidation(email)
    }

    if(inpValues.emailID.error === false){
        //.... if it is false i will call server using AXIOS
    }
}
function emailValidation(email) {
    console.log('Email Validation Called, Email = '+ email)
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
        return ('')
    }
    else {
      
        //below codes are executed
        setInpValues({
            ...inpValues,
            emailID: {
                ...inpValues.emailID,
                error: true,
                helperText: 'Please enter valid Email ID' // I can see this text message on browser
            }
        })
    }

    //but when i check the object value in console. it is not updated, why?
    console.table(inpValues)
}
```

I can call `emailValidation(email) function`. it set the values of `error:true, helperText:'Please enter valid Email ID'`,

**helperText** is updated on the browser, but it's not updated on the useState object value

[image: console]

**I tried with prevState like below, still same result**

```
setInpValues(prevInpValues => ({
   ...prevInpValues,
   emailID: {
       ...prevInpValues.emailID,
       error: true,
       helperText: 'Please enter valid Email ID'
       }
    })
)
```

Comment: [state update may be asynchronous - see here for more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), or [this](https://gist.github.com/bpas247/e177a772b293025e5324219d231cf32c) or [this](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#render-batching-and-timing)

Comment: @KcH could you give an example to update an object with prevStateObject as a parameter

Comment: You're using the `prevInpValues` correctly in the final example in your question. The issue is exactly what @KcH said-- setting the state may be async, meaning it'll update before the next render, but hasn't updated yet when you console log it.

Comment: @Nathan ok I understand, so how to do re-render it immediately after I update the value, instead of waiting for the next render

Comment: It will re-render automatically! React re-renders whenever it needs to, in a few conditions. Updating state will schedule a re-render. If you want to see it working, put your console log statement outside of `useEffect`, in the actual body of your functional component. It will then get called every render, and you should see it happening immediately after setting state.

Comment: @Nathan it takes time to learn how to use `useEffect`. now i got it. it works fine. I pass the second parameter `inpValues.emailID.error` in useEffect, so once set values, the component is reflecting immediately. Many thanks. your comments supposed to be as Answer, not as a comments

Answer (score 0):

as it was said in the comments updating state maybe async but if you want to ensure that your state updating is synchronous you can put setState in a flushSync function.
so you can rewrite `emailValidation` function as following.

```
function emailValidation(email) {
console.log('Email Validation Called, Email = '+ email)
if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
    return ('')
}
else {
  
    //below codes are executed
    flushSync(() => {setInpValues({
        ...inpValues,
        emailID: {
            ...inpValues.emailID,
            error: true,
            helperText: 'Please enter valid Email ID' // I can see this text message on browser
        }
    })})
}

//but when i check the object value in console. it is not updated, why?
console.table(inpValues) }
```

this way `console.table(inpValues)` will receive updated values of state and DOM is ensured to be updated with new values